# Getting an error while trying to import msql dump

Tags: mysql

While trying to import database tables, I am getting an error that says :

```
    Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO `rn2_cache_menu` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`) VALUES

('links:management:tree-data:en:ec99d3452fef1ede622e66c68ba908b1dad455aa71f5e68648aeec6488b89c88', 
0x613a323a7b733a343a2274726565223b613a313a7b693a313b613a323a7b733a343a226c696e6b223b613a34323a7b733a393a226d656e755f6e616d65223b733a3130
3a226d616e6167656d656e74223b733a343a226d6c6964223b733a313a2231223b733a343a22706c6964223b733a313a2230223b733a393a226c696e6b5f70617468223b73
3a353a2261646d696e223b733a31313a22726f757465725f70617468223b733a353a2261646d696e223b733a31303a226c696e6b5f7469746c65223b733a31343a2241646d
696e697374726174696f6e223b733a373a226f7074696f6e73223b733a363a22613a303a7b7d223b733a363a226d6f64756c65223b733a363a2273797374656d223b733a3
63a2268696464656e223b733a313a2230223b733a383a2265787465726e616c223b733a313a2230223b733a31323a226861735f6368696c6472656e223b733a313a22312
23b733a383a22657870616e646564223b733a313a2230223b733a363a22776569676874223b733a313a2239223b733a353a226465707468223b733a313a22312[...]

MySQL said: Documentation

#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

What does this error mean ?

I have already configured `max_allowed_packet` under `[mysqldump]` to `max_allowed_packet = 16M`.

***Note*** : Of some 150 tables, only 22 tables get imported along with this error !

Comment: That's only the client side value. What about the value of `max_allowed_packet` in the section `mysqld`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check if the connection exists and re-establish it if it is not there.

Also you mat try to increase the timeout of variable like this:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=300;
SET @@LOCAL.wait_timeout=300;
```

or you may try to further increase the ma_allowed_packet to 64M in my.cnf file

```
max_allowed_packet=64M
wait_timeout= 6000
```

Comment: @SuhailGupta:- Did you try to change the max_allowed_packet size to 64M in your my.cnf file? Updated my answer as well!

Comment: Yes I changed. But, I am getting the same error. I didn't find `wait_timeout` in `.ini` file

Comment: @SuhailGupta:- Thats strange. Did you checked:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Comment: @SuhailGupta:- Also did you mysql restarted the service after making the changes in the file?